# Insert four spaces instead of tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keycode

I am trying to insert four spaces when the tab key is pressed. I was using the following code (see `spaces = "\t"`), but when I switch it to `spaces = "    "` only one space is inserted when I press tab. I also tried " " + " " + " " + " ":

```
$(function () {
  $('textarea').keydown(function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (keyCode == 9) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var start = $(this).get(0).selectionStart;
      var end = $(this).get(0).selectionEnd;

      // set textarea value to: text before caret + tab + text after caret
      spaces = "\t"
      $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, start)
                  + spaces 
                  + $(this).val().substring(end));

      // put caret at right position again
      $(this).get(0).selectionStart =
      $(this).get(0).selectionEnd = start + 1;
    }
  });
});
```

NOTE: This is to insert spaces in a browser-based textarea/ide.

Comment: works for me in Chrome/IE9/FF32 - http://jsfiddle.net/17auq970/ - which browser are you using?

Comment: Not exactly related, but the `e.which` check is not needed, jQuery normalizes the property for you (`which`).

Comment: Thanks @Teemu good thought

Comment: You could try specifically setting the `font-family` to `monospace`. Otherwise this works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code works fine but you simply put caret to the wrong place. Change the last line to:

```
this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + spaces.length;
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/qdqrs3cw/

Comment: @maudulus You are welcome `:)` Also in the demo I replaced `$(this).get(0).selection...` with internally the same alternative `this.selection...` and other minor bits to make the code run faster and look better.

Answer (score -1):

try to insert `"&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"` instead of four spaces

PS sorry have not seen that spaces are needed in textarea, in this case HTML entities will no help

Comment: `<textarea>` should handle four spaces normally.

Comment: I tried this, but it inserts "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp" as as a string in the textarea.